# Installing libraries in non standard location and using them to install a software

Tags: linux, compilation, terminal, installation

I am trying to install a software on a cluster running Linux without root. However, the software requires some non-standard libraries before it could be installed. I installed the required libraries in my home directory. When I used ./configure to compile the software's source code, I got an error message saying that it couldn't find library files.
I tried using CPPFLAGS, LDFLAGS, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to tell the compiler where to find the libraries, but it did not seem to work.

How can I install a non-standard library without administrative privileges and tell the compiler where to find that library? Should I also do the same thing for other libraries too?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the exact process for doing so entirely depends on how the software's actual script, and/or Makefile, and/or code. There is no universal answer that works with every software package in existence. Each one's configuration script is unique, and different.

It also depends, in some part, to how the libraries get installed in the nonstandard location. Quite often the library package would include one of several configuration mechanisms that applications that use the library must use in order to configure themselves to the library; a part of which includes the necessary mojo to link the software application to put the correct RPATH into the software application's executable, so that it can load the libraries from the right location; this typically involves the variables you mentioned. One thing you didn't mention is specifying the -R flag to set the RPATH in the executable.

So, the only answer here is for you to keep digging into the library's and the application's configuration scripts, and try to figure it out. There's just no other way to do this, except by brute force. In many cases, it's just not possible to do what you're trying to do "out of the box", and it becomes necessary to patch one or the other's configure script, so that the "right thing" happens.

Answer (score 0):

Set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` while building binaries that link against previously installed libraries:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/user/dir/install/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

When executing binaries compiled against those libraries, set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/user/dir/install/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

If you execute binaries installed in non-standard locations, set `PATH` too:

```
export PATH="/home/user/dir/install/sbin:/home/user/dir/install/bin:$PATH"
```

You might want to set the last two in your `.bashrc` for future use.

Putting the previous variable settings at the end of the string gives higher precedence to the non-standard library and binary locations, if files exist in both places. Consider switching them around if you prefer using programs installed through your package manager.